# bootstrap dropdown list not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i click on dropdown button, list does does not drop down.
I have added 3 links from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ (Bootstrap CDN) to include bootstrap.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">

            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is a little mistake.Coding first line is <div class="Dropdown">

Comment: What is the error in the debugger ? Have you link jQuery too (before loading bootstrap.js)??

Comment: This code works http://jsfiddle.net/by73ozu1/... as TheLittlePig said, check your ressources. You must have first jQuery.js, then bootstrap.js loaded in your app.

Comment: Code is working perfectly. Have you linkd boostrap jquery? @IrfanWattoo

Comment: i had not added jquery.js that's why it was not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this lines into your html in the `<head>` :

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jquery 1.11 minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```